# Please update this addon to work in 2.8

Tags: python, export

I cant code/program to save my life and this exporter is the only reason I have 2.79 on my system at this point. Maybe a bit weird not to be asking for help doing it but it is my situation. Any help is appreciated though and thanks for taking the time to read my post!

Here's the Add-on code:

```
# ***** BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK ***** 
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License 
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version. 
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
# GNU General Public License for more details. 
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License 
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, 
# Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA. 
#
# ***** END GPL LICENCE BLOCK *****
#
#Updates and additions for Blender 2.6X by Derek McPherson
#
bl_info = {
    "name": "GZDoom .MD3",
    "author": "Derek McPherson, Xembie, PhaethonH, Bob Holcomb, Damien McGinnes, Robert (Tr3B) Beckebans, CoDEmanX, Nash Muhandes",
    "version": (1, 6, 3), # 11th of July 2012 - CoDEmanX
    "blender": (2, 6, 3),
    "location": "File > Export > GZDoom model (.md3)",
    "description": "Export mesh to GZDoom model with vertex animation (.md3)",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "http://www.katsbits.com/smforum/index.php?topic=275.0",
    "category": "Import-Export"}

import bpy, struct, math, os, time

##### User options: Exporter default settings
default_logtype = 'console' ## console, overwrite, append
default_dumpall = False 
default_triangulate = True


MAX_QPATH = 64

MD3_IDENT = "IDP3"
MD3_VERSION = 15
MD3_MAX_TAGS = 16
MD3_MAX_SURFACES = 32
MD3_MAX_FRAMES = 1024
MD3_MAX_SHADERS = 256
MD3_MAX_VERTICES = 8192    #4096
MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES = 16384  #8192  
MD3_XYZ_SCALE = 64



class md3Vert:
    xyz = []
    normal = 0
    binaryFormat = "<3hH"

    def __init__(self):
        self.xyz = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.normal = 0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    # copied from PhaethonH <phaethon@linux.ucla.edu> md3.py
    def Decode(self, latlng):
        lat = (latlng >> 8) & 0xFF;
        lng = (latlng) & 0xFF;
        lat *= math.pi / 128;
        lng *= math.pi / 128;
        x = math.cos(lat) * math.sin(lng)
        y = math.sin(lat) * math.sin(lng)
        z =                 math.cos(lng)
        retval = [ x, y, z ]
        return retval

    # copied from PhaethonH <phaethon@linux.ucla.edu> md3.py
    def Encode(self, normal):
        x = normal[0]
        y = normal[1]
        z = normal[2]
        # normalize
        l = math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z))
        if l == 0:
            return 0
        x = x/l
        y = y/l
        z = z/l

        if (x == 0.0) & (y == 0.0) :
            if z > 0.0:
                return 0
            else:
                return (128 << 8)

        lng = math.acos(z) * 255 / (2 * math.pi)
        lat = math.atan2(y, x) * 255 / (2 * math.pi)
        retval = ((int(lat) & 0xFF) << 8) | (int(lng) & 0xFF)
        return retval

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 4
        tmpData[0] = int(self.xyz[0] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[1] = int(self.xyz[1] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[2] = int(self.xyz[2] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[3] = self.normal
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3])
        file.write(data)

class md3TexCoord:
    u = 0.0
    v = 0.0

    binaryFormat = "<2f"

    def __init__(self):
        self.u = 0.0
        self.v = 0.0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 2
        tmpData[0] = self.u
        tmpData[1] = 1.0 - self.v
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1])
        file.write(data)

class md3Triangle:
    indexes = []

    binaryFormat = "<3i"

    def __init__(self):
        self.indexes = [ 0, 0, 0 ]

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 3
        tmpData[0] = self.indexes[0]
        tmpData[1] = self.indexes[2] # reverse
        tmpData[2] = self.indexes[1] # reverse
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat,tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2])
        file.write(data)

class md3Shader:
    name = ""
    index = 0

    binaryFormat = "<%dsi" % MAX_QPATH

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.index = 0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 2
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[1] = self.index
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1])
        file.write(data)

class md3Surface:
    ident = ""
    name = ""
    flags = 0
    numFrames = 0
    numShaders = 0
    numVerts = 0
    numTriangles = 0
    ofsTriangles = 0
    ofsShaders = 0
    ofsUV = 0
    ofsVerts = 0
    ofsEnd = 0
    shaders = []
    triangles = []
    uv = []
    verts = []

    binaryFormat = "<4s%ds10i" % MAX_QPATH  # 1 int, name, then 10 ints

    def __init__(self):
        self.ident = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.flags = 0
        self.numFrames = 0
        self.numShaders = 0
        self.numVerts = 0
        self.numTriangles = 0
        self.ofsTriangles = 0
        self.ofsShaders = 0
        self.ofsUV = 0
        self.ofsVerts = 0
        self.ofsEnd
        self.shaders = []
        self.triangles = []
        self.uv = []
        self.verts = []

    def GetSize(self):
        sz = struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)
        self.ofsTriangles = sz
        for t in self.triangles:
            sz += t.GetSize()
        self.ofsShaders = sz
        for s in self.shaders:
            sz += s.GetSize()
        self.ofsUV = sz
        for u in self.uv:
            sz += u.GetSize()
        self.ofsVerts = sz
        for v in self.verts:
            sz += v.GetSize()
        self.ofsEnd = sz
        return self.ofsEnd

    def Save(self, file):
        self.GetSize()
        tmpData = [0] * 12
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.ident)
        tmpData[1] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[2] = self.flags
        tmpData[3] = self.numFrames
        tmpData[4] = self.numShaders
        tmpData[5] = self.numVerts
        tmpData[6] = self.numTriangles
        tmpData[7] = self.ofsTriangles
        tmpData[8] = self.ofsShaders
        tmpData[9] = self.ofsUV
        tmpData[10] = self.ofsVerts
        tmpData[11] = self.ofsEnd
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0],tmpData[1],tmpData[2],tmpData[3],tmpData[4],tmpData[5],tmpData[6],tmpData[7],tmpData[8],tmpData[9],tmpData[10],tmpData[11])
        file.write(data)

        # write the tri data
        for t in self.triangles:
            t.Save(file)

        # save the shader coordinates
        for s in self.shaders:
            s.Save(file)

        # save the uv info
        for u in self.uv:
            u.Save(file)

        # save the verts
        for v in self.verts:
            v.Save(file)

class md3Tag:
    name = ""
    origin = []
    axis = []

    binaryFormat="<%ds3f9f" % MAX_QPATH

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.origin = [0, 0, 0]
        self.axis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 13
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[1] = float(self.origin[0])
        tmpData[2] = float(self.origin[1])
        tmpData[3] = float(self.origin[2])
        tmpData[4] = float(self.axis[0])
        tmpData[5] = float(self.axis[1])
        tmpData[6] = float(self.axis[2])
        tmpData[7] = float(self.axis[3])
        tmpData[8] = float(self.axis[4])
        tmpData[9] = float(self.axis[5])
        tmpData[10] = float(self.axis[6])
        tmpData[11] = float(self.axis[7])
        tmpData[12] = float(self.axis[8])
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0],tmpData[1],tmpData[2],tmpData[3],tmpData[4],tmpData[5],tmpData[6], tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10], tmpData[11], tmpData[12])
        file.write(data)

class md3Frame:
    mins = 0
    maxs = 0
    localOrigin = 0
    radius = 0.0
    name = ""

    binaryFormat="<3f3f3ff16s"

    def __init__(self):
        self.mins = [0, 0, 0]
        self.maxs = [0, 0, 0]
        self.localOrigin = [0, 0, 0]
        self.radius = 0.0
        self.name = ""

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 11
        tmpData[0] = self.mins[0]
        tmpData[1] = self.mins[1]
        tmpData[2] = self.mins[2]
        tmpData[3] = self.maxs[0]
        tmpData[4] = self.maxs[1]
        tmpData[5] = self.maxs[2]
        tmpData[6] = self.localOrigin[0]
        tmpData[7] = self.localOrigin[1]
        tmpData[8] = self.localOrigin[2]
        tmpData[9] = self.radius
        tmpData[10] = str.encode("frame" + self.name)
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0],tmpData[1],tmpData[2],tmpData[3],tmpData[4],tmpData[5],tmpData[6],tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10])
        file.write(data)

class md3Object:
    # header structure
    ident = ""          # this is used to identify the file (must be IDP3)
    version = 0         # the version number of the file (Must be 15)
    name = ""
    flags = 0
    numFrames = 0
    numTags = 0
    numSurfaces = 0
    numSkins = 0
    ofsFrames = 0
    ofsTags = 0
    ofsSurfaces = 0
    ofsEnd = 0
    frames = []
    tags = []
    surfaces = []

    binaryFormat="<4si%ds9i" % MAX_QPATH  # little-endian (<), 17 integers (17i)

    def __init__(self):
        self.ident = 0
        self.version = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.flags = 0
        self.numFrames = 0
        self.numTags = 0
        self.numSurfaces = 0
        self.numSkins = 0
        self.ofsFrames = 0
        self.ofsTags = 0
        self.ofsSurfaces = 0
        self.ofsEnd = 0
        self.frames = []
        self.tags = []
        self.surfaces = []

    def GetSize(self):
        self.ofsFrames = struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)
        self.ofsTags = self.ofsFrames
        for f in self.frames:
            self.ofsTags += f.GetSize()
        self.ofsSurfaces += self.ofsTags
        for t in self.tags:
            self.ofsSurfaces += t.GetSize()
        self.ofsEnd = self.ofsSurfaces
        for s in self.surfaces:
            self.ofsEnd += s.GetSize()
        return self.ofsEnd

    def Save(self, file):
        self.GetSize()
        tmpData = [0] * 12
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.ident)
        tmpData[1] = self.version
        tmpData[2] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[3] = self.flags
        tmpData[4] = self.numFrames
        tmpData[5] = self.numTags
        tmpData[6] = self.numSurfaces
        tmpData[7] = self.numSkins
        tmpData[8] = self.ofsFrames
        tmpData[9] = self.ofsTags
        tmpData[10] = self.ofsSurfaces
        tmpData[11] = self.ofsEnd

        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0],tmpData[1],tmpData[2],tmpData[3],tmpData[4],tmpData[5],tmpData[6],tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10], tmpData[11])
        file.write(data)

        for f in self.frames:
            f.Save(file)

        for t in self.tags:
            t.Save(file)

        for s in self.surfaces:
            s.Save(file)


def message(log,msg):
  if log:
    log.write(msg + "\n")
  else:
    print(msg)

class md3Settings:
  def __init__(self,
               savepath,
               name,
               logtype,
               dumpall=False,
               triangulate=False,
               scale=1.0,
               offsetx=0.0,
               offsety=0.0,
               offsetz=0.0):
    self.savepath = savepath
    self.name = name
    self.logtype = logtype
    self.dumpall = dumpall
    self.triangulate = triangulate
    self.scale = scale
    self.offsetx = offsetx
    self.offsety = offsety
    self.offsetz = offsetz

def print_md3(log,md3,dumpall):
  message(log,"Header Information")
  message(log,"Ident: " + str(md3.ident))
  message(log,"Version: " + str(md3.version))
  message(log,"Name: " + md3.name)
  message(log,"Flags: " + str(md3.flags))
  message(log,"Number of Frames: " + str(md3.numFrames))
  message(log,"Number of Tags: " + str(md3.numTags))
  message(log,"Number of Surfaces: " + str(md3.numSurfaces))
  message(log,"Number of Skins: " + str(md3.numSkins))
  message(log,"Offset Frames: " + str(md3.ofsFrames))
  message(log,"Offset Tags: " + str(md3.ofsTags))
  message(log,"Offset Surfaces: " + str(md3.ofsSurfaces))
  message(log,"Offset end: " + str(md3.ofsEnd))

  if dumpall:
    message(log,"Frames:")
    for f in md3.frames:
      message(log," Mins: " + str(f.mins[0]) + " " + str(f.mins[1]) + " " + str(f.mins[2]))
      message(log," Maxs: " + str(f.maxs[0]) + " " + str(f.maxs[1]) + " " + str(f.maxs[2]))
      message(log," Origin(local): " + str(f.localOrigin[0]) + " " + str(f.localOrigin[1]) + " " + str(f.localOrigin[2]))
      message(log," Radius: " + str(f.radius))
      message(log," Name: " + f.name)

    message(log,"Tags:")
    for t in md3.tags:
      message(log," Name: " + t.name)
      message(log," Origin: " + str(t.origin[0]) + " " + str(t.origin[1]) + " " + str(t.origin[2]))
      message(log," Axis[0]: " + str(t.axis[0]) + " " + str(t.axis[1]) + " " + str(t.axis[2]))
      message(log," Axis[1]: " + str(t.axis[3]) + " " + str(t.axis[4]) + " " + str(t.axis[5]))
      message(log," Axis[2]: " + str(t.axis[6]) + " " + str(t.axis[7]) + " " + str(t.axis[8]))

    message(log,"Surfaces:")
    for s in md3.surfaces:
      message(log," Ident: " + s.ident)
      message(log," Name: " + s.name)
      message(log," Flags: " + str(s.flags))
      message(log," # of Frames: " + str(s.numFrames))
      message(log," # of Shaders: " + str(s.numShaders))
      message(log," # of Verts: " + str(s.numVerts))
      message(log," # of Triangles: " + str(s.numTriangles))
      message(log," Offset Triangles: " + str(s.ofsTriangles))
      message(log," Offset UVs: " + str(s.ofsUV))
      message(log," Offset Verts: " + str(s.ofsVerts))
      message(log," Offset End: " + str(s.ofsEnd))
      message(log," Shaders:")
      for shader in s.shaders:
        message(log,"  Name: " + shader.name)
        message(log,"  Index: " + str(shader.index))
      message(log," Triangles:")
      for tri in s.triangles:
        message(log,"  Indexes: " + str(tri.indexes[0]) + " " + str(tri.indexes[1]) + " " + str(tri.indexes[2]))
      message(log," UVs:")
      for uv in s.uv:
        message(log,"  U: " + str(uv.u))
        message(log,"  V: " + str(uv.v)) 
      message(log," Verts:")
      for vert in s.verts:
        message(log,"  XYZ: " + str(vert.xyz[0]) + " " + str(vert.xyz[1]) + " " + str(vert.xyz[2]))
        message(log,"  Normal: " + str(vert.normal))

  shader_count = 0
  vert_count = 0
  tri_count = 0
  for surface in md3.surfaces:
    shader_count += surface.numShaders
    tri_count += surface.numTriangles
    vert_count += surface.numVerts
    if surface.numShaders >= MD3_MAX_SHADERS:
      message(log,"!Warning: Shader limit (" + str(surface.numShaders) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_SHADERS) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)
    if surface.numVerts >= MD3_MAX_VERTICES:
      message(log,"!Warning: Vertex limit (" + str(surface.numVerts) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_VERTICES) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)
    if surface.numTriangles >= MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES:
      message(log,"!Warning: Triangle limit (" + str(surface.numTriangles) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)

  if md3.numTags >= MD3_MAX_TAGS:
    message(log,"!Warning: Tag limit (" + str(md3.numTags) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_TAGS) + ") reached for md3!")
  if md3.numSurfaces >= MD3_MAX_SURFACES:
    message(log,"!Warning: Surface limit (" + str(md3.numSurfaces) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_SURFACES) + ") reached for md3!")
  if md3.numFrames >= MD3_MAX_FRAMES:
    message(log,"!Warning: Frame limit (" + str(md3.numFrames) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_FRAMES) + ") reached for md3!")

  message(log,"Total Shaders: " + str(shader_count))
  message(log,"Total Triangles: " + str(tri_count))
  message(log,"Total Vertices: " + str(vert_count))

def save_md3(settings):###################### MAIN BODY     
  starttime = time.clock()#start timer
  newlogpath = os.path.splitext(settings.savepath)[0] + ".log"
  dumpall = settings.dumpall
  if settings.logtype == "append":
    log = open(newlogpath,"a")
  elif settings.logtype == "overwrite":
    log = open(newlogpath,"w")
  else:
    log = 0
  message(log,"######################BEGIN######################")
  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
  md3 = md3Object()
  md3.ident = MD3_IDENT
  md3.version = MD3_VERSION
  md3.name = settings.name
  md3.numFrames = (bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1) - bpy.context.scene.frame_start
  global actobject
  global convert_to_tris
  actobject = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
  selobjects = bpy.context.selected_objects

######Find scale value for fitting very small objects to md3 world space
  scale_md3 = True
  if settings.scale != 1:
    scale_md3 = False #Allows manual scaling to override auto scaling
  scene_maxs = [0, 0, 0]
  if scale_md3 == True:
    for obj in selobjects:
      if obj.type == 'MESH':

        # CoDEmanX: Bmesh
        if not obj.data.tessfaces and obj.data.polygons:
          obj.data.calc_tessface()

        obj_maxs = [0] * 3
        for frame in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start,bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1):
          bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
          for i in range(0,3):
            if obj.dimensions[i] == 0:
              scale_md3 = False #Cancel if any object has an axis dimension of 0 (2D Objects)
            obj_maxs[i] = round(max(obj_maxs[i],obj.dimensions[i]),5)          
          if dumpall: message(log,"Object bounds for"+str(frame)+str(obj.dimensions))
        if dumpall: message(log,"Object maxs"+str(obj_maxs))
        scene_maxs = max(scene_maxs,obj_maxs)
      if dumpall: message(log,"Selected objects maxs"+str(scene_maxs))
    if scale_md3 == True:
      scene_minimum = min(scene_maxs[0],scene_maxs[1],scene_maxs[2])
      scene_maximum = max(scene_maxs[0],scene_maxs[1],scene_maxs[2])
      if dumpall: message(log,"Selected objects min single axis dimension "+str(scene_minimum))
      if dumpall: message(log,"Selected objects max single axis dimension "+str(scene_maximum))
      if scene_minimum < 25:
        my_scale = round(25/scene_minimum,2)
        if scene_maximum * my_scale > 750:#Selected Objects bounding box ratio for auto scale is
                        # 1 min axis dimension to 30 max axis dimension
          scale_md3 = False #Cancel if autoscaling makes any object too big (??750??)
      else: scale_md3 = False #for objects large enough not to need scaling   
    if scale_md3 == True:
      #settings.scale = my_scale      
      message(log,"Scaling export by a value of " + str(my_scale) + " to fit MD3 space")

####### Convert to MD3 
  for obj in selobjects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
      convert_to_tris = False      
      bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_start)

      for face in obj.data.tessfaces:
        if (len(face.vertices) > 3) & settings.triangulate == True:
          convert_to_tris = True                             
      if convert_to_tris == True:
        me_SaveMesh = obj.data.copy()      
        scene = bpy.context.scene      
        scene.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris()
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        scene.objects.active = actobject      
        message(log,"Converted quads in UV map of " + obj.name + " to tris.")
        message(log,"Exporting UV texture coordinates for " + obj.name)
        message(log,"Exporting " + obj.name)
        nobj = obj.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, 'PREVIEW')
        obj.data = me_SaveMesh
        me_SaveMesh = []        
      else:
        message(log,"Exporting UV texture coordinates for " + obj.name)
        message(log,"Exporting " + obj.name)
        nobj = obj.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, 'PREVIEW')

      UVImage = nobj.tessface_uv_textures[0] # ERROR: An object needs to be unwrapped. 
      texCoords = UVImage.data
      nsurface = md3Surface() 
      nsurface.name = obj.name
      nsurface.ident = MD3_IDENT
      nshader = md3Shader()
      #Add only 1 shader per surface/object
      try:
        #Using custom properties allows a longer string
        nshader.name = obj["md3shader"]#Set Property Value to shader path/filename
      except:
        if obj.active_material:      
          nshader.name = obj.active_material.name
        else:
          nshader.name = "NULL"      
      nsurface.shaders.append(nshader)
      nsurface.numShaders = 1

      vertlist = []
      myInt = 0
      for f,face in enumerate(nobj.tessfaces):
        faceTexCoords = texCoords[myInt] 
        myInt = myInt + 1 
        ntri = md3Triangle()

        if len(face.vertices) != 3:
          message(log,"Found a nontriangle face in object " + obj.name)
          continue

        for v,vert_index in enumerate(face.vertices):
          uv_u = round(faceTexCoords.uv[v][0],5)
          uv_v = round(faceTexCoords.uv[v][1],5)
          match = 0
          match_index = 0
          for i,vi in enumerate(vertlist):
            if vi == vert_index:
              if nsurface.uv[i].u == uv_u and nsurface.uv[i].v == uv_v:
                match = 1
                match_index = i

          if match == 0:
            vertlist.append(vert_index)
            ntri.indexes[v] = nsurface.numVerts
            ntex = md3TexCoord()
            ntex.u = uv_u
            ntex.v = uv_v
            nsurface.uv.append(ntex)
            nsurface.numVerts += 1
          else:
            ntri.indexes[v] = match_index
        nsurface.triangles.append(ntri)
        nsurface.numTriangles += 1

      for frame in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start,bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        for face in obj.data.tessfaces:
          if (len(face.vertices) > 3) & settings.triangulate == True:
            convert_to_tris = True                             
        if convert_to_tris == True:
          me_SaveMesh = obj.data.copy()      
          scene = bpy.context.scene      
          scene.objects.active = obj
          bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
          bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
          bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris()
          bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
          scene.objects.active = actobject      
          if dumpall:message(log,"Converted quads in frame " + str(frame) + " of " + obj.name + " to tris.")
          if dumpall:message(log,"Exporting frame " + str(frame) + " of " + obj.name)
          fobj = obj.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, 'PREVIEW')
          obj.data = me_SaveMesh
          me_SaveMesh = []        
        else:
          if dumpall:message(log,"Exporting frame " + str(frame) + " of " + obj.name)
          fobj = obj.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, 'PREVIEW')        
        nframe = md3Frame()
        nframe.name = str(frame)
        ## Apply location data from objects and armatures
        if obj.parent == "True":
          if obj.parent.name == "Armature":
            if obj.find_armature() != NULL:
              skel_loc = obj.parent.location      
              nframe.localOrigin = obj.location - skel_loc
              my_matrix = obj.matrix_world * obj.matrix_parent_inverse
        else:
          nframe.localOrigin = obj.location
          my_matrix = obj.matrix_world

        ## Locate, sort, encode verts and normals   
        for vi in vertlist:
          vert = fobj.vertices[vi]
          nvert = md3Vert()
          nvert.xyz = my_matrix * vert.co
          nvert.xyz[0] = round((nvert.xyz[0] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetx,5)
          nvert.xyz[1] = round((nvert.xyz[1] * settings.scale) + settings.offsety,5)
          nvert.xyz[2] = round((nvert.xyz[2] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetz,5)
          nvert.normal = nvert.Encode(vert.normal)
          ## mins, maxs, radius... count frames and surfaces
          for i in range(0,3):
            nframe.mins[i] = min(nframe.mins[i],nvert.xyz[i])
            nframe.maxs[i] = max(nframe.maxs[i],nvert.xyz[i])
          minlength = math.sqrt(math.pow(nframe.mins[0],2) + math.pow(nframe.mins[1],2) + math.pow(nframe.mins[2],2))
          maxlength = math.sqrt(math.pow(nframe.maxs[0],2) + math.pow(nframe.maxs[1],2) + math.pow(nframe.maxs[2],2))
          nframe.radius = round(max(minlength,maxlength),5)
          nsurface.verts.append(nvert) 
        md3.frames.append(nframe)
        nsurface.numFrames += 1
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(fobj)
      md3.surfaces.append(nsurface)
      md3.numSurfaces += 1
      bpy.data.meshes.remove(nobj)
      obj = []

    elif obj.type == 'EMPTY':# I think this is all wrong (the matrix locations)
      md3.numTags += 1
      for frame in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start,bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1):
        bpy.context.scene.set_frame(frame)     
        ntag = md3Tag()
        ntag.name = obj.name
        ntag.origin[0] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][0] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetx,5)
        ntag.origin[1] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][1] * settings.scale) + settings.offsety,5)
        ntag.origin[2] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][2] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetz,5)
        ntag.axis[0] = obj.matrix_world[0][0]
        ntag.axis[1] = obj.matrix_world[0][1]
        ntag.axis[2] = obj.matrix_world[0][2]
        ntag.axis[3] = obj.matrix_world[1][0]
        ntag.axis[4] = obj.matrix_world[1][1]
        ntag.axis[5] = obj.matrix_world[1][2]
        ntag.axis[6] = obj.matrix_world[2][0]
        ntag.axis[7] = obj.matrix_world[2][1]
        ntag.axis[8] = obj.matrix_world[2][2]
        md3.tags.append(ntag)

  if bpy.context.selected_objects:
    file = open(settings.savepath, "wb")
    md3.Save(file)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_start)
    print_md3(log,md3,settings.dumpall)
    file.close()
    message(log,"MD3 saved to " + settings.savepath)
    elapsedtime = round(time.clock() - starttime,5)
    message(log,"Elapsed " + str(elapsedtime) + " seconds")
    if scale_md3 == True:
      message(log,"Scaled export by a value of " + str(my_scale) + " to fit MD3 space")      
  else:
    message(log,"Select an object to export!")

  if log:
    print("Logged to",newlogpath)
    log.close()

from bpy.props import *

class ExportMD3(bpy.types.Operator):
  '''Export to .md3'''
  bl_idname = "export.md3"
  bl_label = 'Export MD3'

  logenum = [("console","Console","log to console"),
             ("append","Append","append to log file"),
             ("overwrite","Overwrite","overwrite log file")]

  filepath = StringProperty(subtype = 'FILE_PATH',name="File Path", description="Filepath for exporting", maxlen= 1024, default="")
  md3name = StringProperty(name="MD3 Name", description="MD3 header name / skin path (64 bytes)",maxlen=64,default="")
  md3logtype = EnumProperty(name="Save log", items=logenum, description="File logging options",default =str(default_logtype))
  md3dumpall = BoolProperty(name="Dump all", description="Dump all data for md3 to log",default=default_dumpall)
  md3triangulate = BoolProperty(name="Triangulate", description="Triangulate mesh during export",default=default_triangulate)
  #md3scale = FloatProperty(name="Manual Scale", description="Manually scale all objects from world origin (0,0,0) Overrides auto scaling",default=1.0,precision=5)
  md3offsetx = FloatProperty(name="Offset X", description="Transition scene along x axis",default=0.0,precision=5)
  md3offsety = FloatProperty(name="Offset Y", description="Transition scene along y axis",default=0.0,precision=5)
  md3offsetz = FloatProperty(name="Offset Z", description="Transition scene along z axis",default=0.0,precision=5)

  def execute(self, context):
   settings = md3Settings(savepath = self.properties.filepath,
                          name = self.properties.md3name,
                          logtype = self.properties.md3logtype,
                          dumpall = self.properties.md3dumpall,
                          triangulate = self.properties.md3triangulate,
                          scale = 1.0,
                          offsetx = self.properties.md3offsetx,
                          offsety = self.properties.md3offsety,
                          offsetz = self.properties.md3offsetz)
   save_md3(settings)
   return {'FINISHED'}

  def invoke(self, context, event):
    wm = context.window_manager
    wm.fileselect_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

  @classmethod
  def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object != None

def menu_func(self, context):
  self.layout.operator(ExportMD3.bl_idname, text="GZDoom MD3", icon='BLENDER')

def register():
  bpy.utils.register_class(ExportMD3)
  bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportMD3)
  bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Answer (score 3):

After porting to bmesh, this should work again:

```
# ***** BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK *****
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#    as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#    of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#    Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
#
# ***** END GPL LICENCE BLOCK *****
#
#    Updates and additions for Blender 2.6X by Derek McPherson
#
bl_info = {
    "name": "GZDoom .MD3",
    "author": "Derek McPherson, Xembie, PhaethonH, Bob Holcomb, Damien McGinnes, Robert (Tr3B) Beckebans, CoDEmanX, Nash Muhandes",
    "version": (1, 7, 0),    #      11th of July 2012 - CoDEmanX
    "blender": (2, 82, 0),
    "location": "File > Export > GZDoom model (.md3)",
    "description": "Export mesh to GZDoom model with vertex animation (.md3)",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "http://www.katsbits.com/smforum/index.php?topic=275.0",
    "category": "Import-Export"}

import bpy, struct, math, os, time
import logging
import bmesh

from bpy.props import *
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty, FloatProperty

logger = None

##### User options: Exporter default settings
default_logtype = 'console'    #    console, overwrite, append
default_dumpall = False
default_triangulate = True

MAX_QPATH = 64

MD3_IDENT = "IDP3"
MD3_VERSION = 15
MD3_MAX_TAGS = 16
MD3_MAX_SURFACES = 32
MD3_MAX_FRAMES = 1024
MD3_MAX_SHADERS = 256
MD3_MAX_VERTICES = 8192    #    4096
MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES = 16384    #    8192
MD3_XYZ_SCALE = 64


class md3Vert:
    xyz = []
    normal = 0
    binaryFormat = "<3hH"

    def __init__(self):
        self.xyz = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.normal = 0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    #       copied from PhaethonH <phaethon@linux.ucla.edu> md3.py
    def Decode(self, latlng):
        lat = (latlng >> 8) & 0xFF;
        lng = (latlng) & 0xFF;
        lat *= math.pi / 128;
        lng *= math.pi / 128;
        x = math.cos(lat) * math.sin(lng)
        y = math.sin(lat) * math.sin(lng)
        z = math.cos(lng)
        retval = [ x, y, z ]
        return retval

    #       copied from PhaethonH <phaethon@linux.ucla.edu> md3.py
    def Encode(self, normal):
        #    normalize
        #    improvements as suggested by batFINGER on BSE, reuse the incoming normal
        if normal.length == 0:
            return 0

        x, y, z = normal.normalized()

        if (x == 0.0) & (y == 0.0) :
            if z > 0.0:
                return 0
            else:
                return (128 << 8)

        lng = math.acos(z) * 255 / (2 * math.pi)
        lat = math.atan2(y, x) * 255 / (2 * math.pi)
        retval = ((int(lat) & 0xFF) << 8) | (int(lng) & 0xFF)
        return retval

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 4
        tmpData[0] = int(self.xyz[0] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[1] = int(self.xyz[1] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[2] = int(self.xyz[2] * MD3_XYZ_SCALE)
        tmpData[3] = self.normal
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3])
        file.write(data)


class md3TexCoord:
    u = 0.0
    v = 0.0

    binaryFormat = "<2f"

    def __init__(self):
        self.u = 0.0
        self.v = 0.0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 2
        tmpData[0] = self.u
        tmpData[1] = 1.0 - self.v
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1])
        file.write(data)


class md3Triangle:
    indexes = []

    binaryFormat = "<3i"

    def __init__(self):
        self.indexes = [ 0, 0, 0 ]

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 3
        tmpData[0] = self.indexes[0]
        tmpData[1] = self.indexes[2]    #       reverse
        tmpData[2] = self.indexes[1]    #       reverse
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2])
        file.write(data)


class md3Shader:
    name = ""
    index = 0

    binaryFormat = "<%dsi" % MAX_QPATH

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.index = 0

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 2
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[1] = self.index
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1])
        file.write(data)


class md3Surface:
    ident = ""
    name = ""
    flags = 0
    numFrames = 0
    numShaders = 0
    numVerts = 0
    numTriangles = 0
    ofsTriangles = 0
    ofsShaders = 0
    ofsUV = 0
    ofsVerts = 0
    ofsEnd = 0
    shaders = []
    triangles = []
    uv = []
    verts = []

    binaryFormat = "<4s%ds10i" % MAX_QPATH    #     1 int, name, then 10 ints

    def __init__(self):
        self.ident = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.flags = 0
        self.numFrames = 0
        self.numShaders = 0
        self.numVerts = 0
        self.numTriangles = 0
        self.ofsTriangles = 0
        self.ofsShaders = 0
        self.ofsUV = 0
        self.ofsVerts = 0
        self.ofsEnd
        self.shaders = []
        self.triangles = []
        self.uv = []
        self.verts = []

    def GetSize(self):
        sz = struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)
        self.ofsTriangles = sz
        for t in self.triangles:
            sz += t.GetSize()
        self.ofsShaders = sz
        for s in self.shaders:
            sz += s.GetSize()
        self.ofsUV = sz
        for u in self.uv:
            sz += u.GetSize()
        self.ofsVerts = sz
        for v in self.verts:
            sz += v.GetSize()
        self.ofsEnd = sz
        return self.ofsEnd

    def Save(self, file):
        self.GetSize()
        tmpData = [0] * 12
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.ident)
        tmpData[1] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[2] = self.flags
        tmpData[3] = self.numFrames
        tmpData[4] = self.numShaders
        tmpData[5] = self.numVerts
        tmpData[6] = self.numTriangles
        tmpData[7] = self.ofsTriangles
        tmpData[8] = self.ofsShaders
        tmpData[9] = self.ofsUV
        tmpData[10] = self.ofsVerts
        tmpData[11] = self.ofsEnd
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3], tmpData[4], tmpData[5], tmpData[6], tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10], tmpData[11])
        file.write(data)

        #       write the tri data
        for t in self.triangles:
            t.Save(file)

        #       save the shader coordinates
        for s in self.shaders:
            s.Save(file)

        #       save the uv info
        for u in self.uv:
            u.Save(file)

        #       save the verts
        for v in self.verts:
            v.Save(file)


class md3Tag:
    name = ""
    origin = []
    axis = []

    binaryFormat = "<%ds3f9f" % MAX_QPATH

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.origin = [0, 0, 0]
        self.axis = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 13
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[1] = float(self.origin[0])
        tmpData[2] = float(self.origin[1])
        tmpData[3] = float(self.origin[2])
        tmpData[4] = float(self.axis[0])
        tmpData[5] = float(self.axis[1])
        tmpData[6] = float(self.axis[2])
        tmpData[7] = float(self.axis[3])
        tmpData[8] = float(self.axis[4])
        tmpData[9] = float(self.axis[5])
        tmpData[10] = float(self.axis[6])
        tmpData[11] = float(self.axis[7])
        tmpData[12] = float(self.axis[8])
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3], tmpData[4], tmpData[5], tmpData[6], tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10], tmpData[11], tmpData[12])
        file.write(data)


class md3Frame:
    mins = 0
    maxs = 0
    localOrigin = 0
    radius = 0.0
    name = ""

    binaryFormat = "<3f3f3ff16s"

    def __init__(self):
        self.mins = [0, 0, 0]
        self.maxs = [0, 0, 0]
        self.localOrigin = [0, 0, 0]
        self.radius = 0.0
        self.name = ""

    def GetSize(self):
        return struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)

    def Save(self, file):
        tmpData = [0] * 11
        tmpData[0] = self.mins[0]
        tmpData[1] = self.mins[1]
        tmpData[2] = self.mins[2]
        tmpData[3] = self.maxs[0]
        tmpData[4] = self.maxs[1]
        tmpData[5] = self.maxs[2]
        tmpData[6] = self.localOrigin[0]
        tmpData[7] = self.localOrigin[1]
        tmpData[8] = self.localOrigin[2]
        tmpData[9] = self.radius
        tmpData[10] = str.encode("frame" + self.name)
        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3], tmpData[4], tmpData[5], tmpData[6], tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10])
        file.write(data)


class md3Object:
    #       header structure
    ident = ""    #     this is used to identify the file (must be IDP3)
    version = 0    #        the version number of the file (Must be 15)
    name = ""
    flags = 0
    numFrames = 0
    numTags = 0
    numSurfaces = 0
    numSkins = 0
    ofsFrames = 0
    ofsTags = 0
    ofsSurfaces = 0
    ofsEnd = 0
    frames = []
    tags = []
    surfaces = []

    binaryFormat = "<4si%ds9i" % MAX_QPATH    #     little-endian (<), 17 integers (17i)

    def __init__(self):
        self.ident = 0
        self.version = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.flags = 0
        self.numFrames = 0
        self.numTags = 0
        self.numSurfaces = 0
        self.numSkins = 0
        self.ofsFrames = 0
        self.ofsTags = 0
        self.ofsSurfaces = 0
        self.ofsEnd = 0
        self.frames = []
        self.tags = []
        self.surfaces = []

    def GetSize(self):
        self.ofsFrames = struct.calcsize(self.binaryFormat)
        self.ofsTags = self.ofsFrames
        for f in self.frames:
            self.ofsTags += f.GetSize()
        self.ofsSurfaces += self.ofsTags
        for t in self.tags:
            self.ofsSurfaces += t.GetSize()
        self.ofsEnd = self.ofsSurfaces
        for s in self.surfaces:
            self.ofsEnd += s.GetSize()
        return self.ofsEnd

    def Save(self, file):
        self.GetSize()
        tmpData = [0] * 12
        tmpData[0] = str.encode(self.ident)
        tmpData[1] = self.version
        tmpData[2] = str.encode(self.name)
        tmpData[3] = self.flags
        tmpData[4] = self.numFrames
        tmpData[5] = self.numTags
        tmpData[6] = self.numSurfaces
        tmpData[7] = self.numSkins
        tmpData[8] = self.ofsFrames
        tmpData[9] = self.ofsTags
        tmpData[10] = self.ofsSurfaces
        tmpData[11] = self.ofsEnd

        data = struct.pack(self.binaryFormat, tmpData[0], tmpData[1], tmpData[2], tmpData[3], tmpData[4], tmpData[5], tmpData[6], tmpData[7], tmpData[8], tmpData[9], tmpData[10], tmpData[11])
        file.write(data)

        for f in self.frames:
            f.Save(file)

        for t in self.tags:
            t.Save(file)

        for s in self.surfaces:
            s.Save(file)


class md3Settings:

    def __init__(self,
                             savepath,
                             name,
                             logtype,
                             dumpall = False,
                             triangulate = False,
                             scale = 1.0,
                             offsetx = 0.0,
                             offsety = 0.0,
                             offsetz = 0.0):
        self.savepath = savepath
        self.name = name
        self.logtype = logtype
        self.dumpall = dumpall
        self.triangulate = triangulate
        self.scale = scale
        self.offsetx = offsetx
        self.offsety = offsety
        self.offsetz = offsetz


def print_md3(logger, md3, dumpall):
    logger.info("Header Information")
    logger.info("Ident: " + str(md3.ident))
    logger.info("Version: " + str(md3.version))
    logger.info("Name: " + md3.name)
    logger.info("Flags: " + str(md3.flags))
    logger.info("Number of Frames: " + str(md3.numFrames))
    logger.info("Number of Tags: " + str(md3.numTags))
    logger.info("Number of Surfaces: " + str(md3.numSurfaces))
    logger.info("Number of Skins: " + str(md3.numSkins))
    logger.info("Offset Frames: " + str(md3.ofsFrames))
    logger.info("Offset Tags: " + str(md3.ofsTags))
    logger.info("Offset Surfaces: " + str(md3.ofsSurfaces))
    logger.info("Offset end: " + str(md3.ofsEnd))

    if dumpall:
        logger.info("Frames:")
        for f in md3.frames:
            logger.info(" Mins: " + str(f.mins[0]) + " " + str(f.mins[1]) + " " + str(f.mins[2]))
            logger.info(" Maxs: " + str(f.maxs[0]) + " " + str(f.maxs[1]) + " " + str(f.maxs[2]))
            logger.info(" Origin(local): " + str(f.localOrigin[0]) + " " + str(f.localOrigin[1]) + " " + str(f.localOrigin[2]))
            logger.info(" Radius: " + str(f.radius))
            logger.info(" Name: " + f.name)

        logger.info("Tags:")
        for t in md3.tags:
            logger.info(" Name: " + t.name)
            logger.info(" Origin: " + str(t.origin[0]) + " " + str(t.origin[1]) + " " + str(t.origin[2]))
            logger.info(" Axis[0]: " + str(t.axis[0]) + " " + str(t.axis[1]) + " " + str(t.axis[2]))
            logger.info(" Axis[1]: " + str(t.axis[3]) + " " + str(t.axis[4]) + " " + str(t.axis[5]))
            logger.info(" Axis[2]: " + str(t.axis[6]) + " " + str(t.axis[7]) + " " + str(t.axis[8]))

        logger.info("Surfaces:")
        for s in md3.surfaces:
            logger.info(" Ident: " + s.ident)
            logger.info(" Name: " + s.name)
            logger.info(" Flags: " + str(s.flags))
            logger.info(" # of Frames: " + str(s.numFrames))
            logger.info(" # of Shaders: " + str(s.numShaders))
            logger.info(" # of Verts: " + str(s.numVerts))
            logger.info(" # of Triangles: " + str(s.numTriangles))
            logger.info(" Offset Triangles: " + str(s.ofsTriangles))
            logger.info(" Offset UVs: " + str(s.ofsUV))
            logger.info(" Offset Verts: " + str(s.ofsVerts))
            logger.info(" Offset End: " + str(s.ofsEnd))
            logger.info(" Shaders:")
            for shader in s.shaders:
                logger.info("   Name: " + shader.name)
                logger.info("   Index: " + str(shader.index))
            logger.info(" Triangles:")
            for tri in s.triangles:
                logger.info("   Indexes: " + str(tri.indexes[0]) + " " + str(tri.indexes[1]) + " " + str(tri.indexes[2]))
            logger.info(" UVs:")
            for uv in s.uv:
                logger.info("   U: " + str(uv.u))
                logger.info("   V: " + str(uv.v))
            logger.info(" Verts:")
            for vert in s.verts:
                logger.info("   XYZ: " + str(vert.xyz[0]) + " " + str(vert.xyz[1]) + " " + str(vert.xyz[2]))
                logger.info("   Normal: " + str(vert.normal))

    shader_count = 0
    vert_count = 0
    tri_count = 0
    for surface in md3.surfaces:
        shader_count += surface.numShaders
        tri_count += surface.numTriangles
        vert_count += surface.numVerts
        if surface.numShaders >= MD3_MAX_SHADERS:
            logger.warning("!Warning: Shader limit (" + str(surface.numShaders) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_SHADERS) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)
        if surface.numVerts >= MD3_MAX_VERTICES:
            logger.warning("!Warning: Vertex limit (" + str(surface.numVerts) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_VERTICES) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)
        if surface.numTriangles >= MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES:
            logger.warning("!Warning: Triangle limit (" + str(surface.numTriangles) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_TRIANGLES) + ") reached for surface " + surface.name)

    if md3.numTags >= MD3_MAX_TAGS:
        logger.warning("!Warning: Tag limit (" + str(md3.numTags) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_TAGS) + ") reached for md3!")
    if md3.numSurfaces >= MD3_MAX_SURFACES:
        logger.warning("!Warning: Surface limit (" + str(md3.numSurfaces) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_SURFACES) + ") reached for md3!")
    if md3.numFrames >= MD3_MAX_FRAMES:
        logger.warning("!Warning: Frame limit (" + str(md3.numFrames) + "/" + str(MD3_MAX_FRAMES) + ") reached for md3!")

    logger.info("Total Shaders: " + str(shader_count))
    logger.info("Total Triangles: " + str(tri_count))
    logger.info("Total Vertices: " + str(vert_count))


def get_elapsed_time(starttime):
    return round(time.clock() - starttime, 5)


def save_md3(context, settings):    ###################### MAIN BODY
    starttime = time.clock()    #           start timer
    newlogpath = os.path.splitext(settings.savepath)[0] + ".log"
    dumpall = settings.dumpall

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    sh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(sh)

    if settings.logtype in ("append", "overwrite"):
        _mode = 'w' if settings.logtype == "overwrite" else 'a'
        fh = logging.FileHandler(newlogpath, mode = _mode)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)

    logger.info("######################BEGIN######################")
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    md3 = md3Object()
    md3.ident = MD3_IDENT
    md3.version = MD3_VERSION
    md3.name = settings.name
    md3.numFrames = (context.scene.frame_end + 1) - context.scene.frame_start
    selobjects = context.selected_objects

    def get_bmesh(context, obj):
        #    use bmesh to convert the source
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_object(obj, context.view_layer.depsgraph)
        bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces = bm.faces)

        return bm

    ####### Convert to MD3
    for obj in selobjects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_start)

            logger.info("Exporting UV texture coordinates for " + obj.name)
            logger.info("Exporting " + obj.name)

            nobj = get_bmesh(context, obj)

            nsurface = md3Surface()
            nsurface.name = obj.name
            nsurface.ident = MD3_IDENT
            nshader = md3Shader()
            #           Add only 1 shader per surface/object
            try:
                #           Using custom properties allows a longer string
                nshader.name = obj["md3shader"]    #            Set Property Value to shader path/filename
            except:
                if obj.active_material:
                    nshader.name = obj.active_material.name
                else:
                    nshader.name = "NULL"
            nsurface.shaders.append(nshader)
            nsurface.numShaders = 1

            vertlist = []

            nobj.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
            uv = nobj.loops.layers.uv.verify()

            logger.debug(f"starting uv calculation after {get_elapsed_time(starttime)} seconds")

            for face in nobj.faces:
                ntri = md3Triangle()

                _curTime = time.clock()

                if len(face.verts) != 3:
                    logger.warning("Found a nontriangle face in object " + obj.name)
                    continue

                for v, vert in enumerate(face.loops):
                    uv_u = round(vert[uv].uv[0], 5)
                    uv_v = round(vert[uv].uv[1], 5)
                    match = False
                    match_index = 0
                    for i, vi in enumerate(vertlist):
                        if vi == vert.vert:
                            if nsurface.uv[i].u == uv_u and nsurface.uv[i].v == uv_v:
                                match = True
                                match_index = i

                    if not match:
                        vertlist.append(vert.vert.index)
                        ntri.indexes[v] = nsurface.numVerts
                        ntex = md3TexCoord()
                        ntex.u = uv_u
                        ntex.v = uv_v
                        nsurface.uv.append(ntex)
                        nsurface.numVerts += 1
                    else:
                        logger.debug(f'matched index {v} to original mesh index {match_index}')
                        ntri.indexes[v] = match_index
                nsurface.triangles.append(ntri)
                nsurface.numTriangles += 1
                logger.debug(f"completed UV calculation for {nsurface.numVerts/3} faces in {get_elapsed_time(_curTime)} seconds")

            logger.debug(f"completed uv calculation after {get_elapsed_time(starttime)} seconds")

            for frame in range(context.scene.frame_start, context.scene.frame_end + 1):
                context.scene.frame_set(frame)

                if dumpall:logger.info("Exporting frame " + str(frame) + " of " + obj.name)
                fobj = get_bmesh(context, obj)
                fobj.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

                nframe = md3Frame()
                nframe.name = str(frame)
                #           # Apply location data from objects and armatures
                if obj.parent == "True":
                    if obj.parent.name == "Armature":
                        if obj.find_armature():
                            skel_loc = obj.parent.location
                            nframe.localOrigin = obj.location - skel_loc
                            my_matrix = obj.matrix_world @ obj.matrix_parent_inverse
                else:
                    nframe.localOrigin = obj.location
                    my_matrix = obj.matrix_world

                #           # Locate, sort, encode verts and normals
                for vi in vertlist:
                    vert = fobj.verts[vi]
                    nvert = md3Vert()
                    nvert.xyz = my_matrix @ vert.co
                    nvert.xyz[0] = round((nvert.xyz[0] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetx, 5)
                    nvert.xyz[1] = round((nvert.xyz[1] * settings.scale) + settings.offsety, 5)
                    nvert.xyz[2] = round((nvert.xyz[2] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetz, 5)
                    nvert.normal = nvert.Encode(vert.normal)
                    #           # mins, maxs, radius... count frames and surfaces
                    for i in range(0, 3):
                        nframe.mins[i] = min(nframe.mins[i], nvert.xyz[i])
                        nframe.maxs[i] = max(nframe.maxs[i], nvert.xyz[i])
                    minlength = math.sqrt(math.pow(nframe.mins[0], 2) + math.pow(nframe.mins[1], 2) + math.pow(nframe.mins[2], 2))
                    maxlength = math.sqrt(math.pow(nframe.maxs[0], 2) + math.pow(nframe.maxs[1], 2) + math.pow(nframe.maxs[2], 2))
                    nframe.radius = round(max(minlength, maxlength), 5)
                    nsurface.verts.append(nvert)
                md3.frames.append(nframe)
                nsurface.numFrames += 1
                fobj.free()
                logger.debug(f"completed mesh calculation for frame {frame} after {get_elapsed_time(starttime)} seconds")

            md3.surfaces.append(nsurface)
            md3.numSurfaces += 1
            nobj.free()
            obj = []

        elif obj.type == 'EMPTY':    #          I think this is all wrong (the matrix locations)
            md3.numTags += 1
            for frame in range(context.scene.frame_start, context.scene.frame_end + 1):
                context.scene.frame_set(frame)
                ntag = md3Tag()
                ntag.name = obj.name
                ntag.origin[0] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][0] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetx, 5)
                ntag.origin[1] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][1] * settings.scale) + settings.offsety, 5)
                ntag.origin[2] = round((obj.matrix_world[3][2] * settings.scale) + settings.offsetz, 5)
                ntag.axis[0] = obj.matrix_world[0][0]
                ntag.axis[1] = obj.matrix_world[0][1]
                ntag.axis[2] = obj.matrix_world[0][2]
                ntag.axis[3] = obj.matrix_world[1][0]
                ntag.axis[4] = obj.matrix_world[1][1]
                ntag.axis[5] = obj.matrix_world[1][2]
                ntag.axis[6] = obj.matrix_world[2][0]
                ntag.axis[7] = obj.matrix_world[2][1]
                ntag.axis[8] = obj.matrix_world[2][2]
                md3.tags.append(ntag)

    if context.selected_objects:
        file = open(settings.savepath, "wb")
        md3.Save(file)
        context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_start)
        print_md3(logger, md3, settings.dumpall)
        file.close()
        logger.info("MD3 saved to " + settings.savepath)
        logger.info(f"Export completed in {get_elapsed_time(starttime)} seconds")
    else:
        logger.info("Select an object to export!")

    if settings.logtype in ("append", "overwrite"):
        logger.debug(f"Logged to {newlogpath}")


class FILE_OT_ExportMD3(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''Export to .md3'''
    bl_idname = "file.export_md3"
    bl_label = 'Export MD3'

    logenum = [("console", "Console", "log to console"),
                         ("append", "Append", "append to log file"),
                         ("overwrite", "Overwrite", "overwrite log file")]

    filepath: StringProperty(subtype = 'FILE_PATH', name = "File Path", description = "Filepath for exporting", maxlen = 1024, default = "")
    md3name: StringProperty(name = "MD3 Name", description = "MD3 header name / skin path (64 bytes)", maxlen = 64, default = "")
    md3logtype: EnumProperty(name = "Save log", items = logenum, description = "File logging options", default = str(default_logtype))
    md3dumpall: BoolProperty(name = "Dump all", description = "Dump all data for md3 to log", default = default_dumpall)
    md3triangulate: BoolProperty(name = "Triangulate", description = "Triangulate mesh during export", default = default_triangulate)

    #           md3scale = FloatProperty(name="Manual Scale", description="Manually scale all objects from world origin (0,0,0) Overrides auto scaling",default=1.0,precision=5)
    md3offsetx: FloatProperty(name = "Offset X", description = "Transition scene along x axis", default = 0.0, precision = 5)
    md3offsety: FloatProperty(name = "Offset Y", description = "Transition scene along y axis", default = 0.0, precision = 5)
    md3offsetz: FloatProperty(name = "Offset Z", description = "Transition scene along z axis", default = 0.0, precision = 5)

    def execute(self, context):
        settings = md3Settings(savepath = self.properties.filepath,
                                name = self.properties.md3name,
                                logtype = self.properties.md3logtype,
                                dumpall = self.properties.md3dumpall,
                                triangulate = self.properties.md3triangulate,
                                scale = 1.0,
                                offsetx = self.properties.md3offsetx,
                                offsety = self.properties.md3offsety,
                                offsetz = self.properties.md3offsetz)

        save_md3(context, settings)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object != None


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(FILE_OT_ExportMD3.bl_idname, text = "GZDoom MD3", icon = 'BLENDER')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(FILE_OT_ExportMD3)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(FILE_OT_ExportMD3)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

However, there are a few things to mention:

- I deactivated a part of the export routine that would scan the current timeline for zero scaling of the objects. I did this mainly because I could not see the point: There is a scale value calculated, but it is never assigned or used in the code later as far as I could see
- I have set Blender 2.82 as the minimum requirement for the Add-on to load. Change `"blender": (2, 82, 0),` to a different sub-version, e.g. `"blender": (2, 80, 0),` if needed
- using bmesh I have seen that modifiers are applied automatically on export. please counter-check if this is the desired behavior

Comment: That appears to work! I put it through a few tests with zero issues so far. Thanks a million times over mate!

Comment: Actually never mind. After an additional test or two, it seems to be messing up the UV's.

Should look like this: https://discordapp.com/channels/416619979723505683/576836366126546958/712279285246722069


But instead looks like this. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/576836366126546958/712279375109816360/unknown.png

Comment: I can confirm that meshes and animations are exporting correctly though.

Comment: @Clayy How can I test .md3 files myself? Is there a viewer for it? Without ever being able to check what happens from source to target, it's impossible to provide working code.

Comment: I am sorry. I keep forgetting there is some know involved. Get the md3 importer for blender 2.6x

If you want to use Neosis, you can simply open the md3 and drag and drop the texture. No animation preview though

Comment: My advice is to not mess with anything relating to how the normals are worked as well. The exporter is target for a source port that messes this up in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for all the deleted messages. Use this program to view:

https://www.richwhitehouse.com/index.php?content=inc_projects.php&filemirror=noesisv4426.zip

Comment: @Clayy thanks, this helps a lot finding the issue. seems like the order of successive UV triangles is modified for some reason, the first triangle exported is correct. Will look into this in the next days

Comment: Thanks mate! I will check this each day.

Comment: @Clayy I have ported the whole mesh conversion part to bmesh now, as this was the only consistent way I know to access the uv layers. Brief testing on my end tells me that uvs now work as they should. As a benefit, the export should have become a bit faster too.

Comment: Above and beyond Mr Guru. .. Be tempted to ditch `l = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))` and use (if not already a vector) `Vector(normal).length`  and `x, y, z = Vector(normal).normalized()`

Comment: @batFINGER good catch, didn't even look into that part of the code. Also switched to Python logging class on the way to dump the messages - benefit is that you now get them in the console AND as a file in case you have a file generated